# Asp.Net Core 2.0 session destroyed each build

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, session-state

I am coming from PHP ecosystem, and now i want upgrade my skills to *Asp.Net Core 2.0*.
There a problem with sessions **since these will be destroyed on each build**, and that's is really annoyng during **development**.

Asp.net authentication system isn't destroyed at **builds/restart**, while sessions are.

There a way to make Sessions persistent like the Auth behavior?

My workaround is; Since i'm using asp.net Auth i could store a unique id and load the session (containing custom object) from the database. Then save it again on changes...

Note: *My application is multi-user so i need to referee the user ID from Session on each request to the database to select related data.*

Comment: Do you use session only to keep the user id? If so, you can remove that completely. Identity already gives you the user id

Comment: That's not a problem at all. It's how sessions *always* worked. That's how they worked in ASP.NET, probably in ASP too. Sessions expire quickly*, typically 20 minutes after the last action by a user anyway

Comment: Are you asking why the *authentication cookie* doesn't work perhaps? That's not related to the session at all. It's not stored in the session either

Comment: Reference to [ASP.NET Core Identity Cookie Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore2x#cookie-settings)

Comment: [Introduction to Identity on ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x) shows a complete configuration example in the Overview section

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Would better if i could save a custom class. If i can not find other solutions, I will save the session in the database, identified by the Claim

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no, the login works, i'm asking about persistent data over builds, since login is, and session not

Comment: By default .NET will store the session data in-memory. When you rebuild an application, the process is recycled which clears the session data. You can adjust the session state mode to something that persists into a new process (see [Session-State Modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx)).

Comment: @Fabio if you use in-memory storage for your session, the data will be lost every time you restart the service, not only every time you build. Have you configured storage or left it to the default storage provider?

Comment: @Fabio in-memory is perfectly fine for single web servers. If you intend to deploy to a farm and use a load balancer you'll have to [configure another provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?tabs=aspnetcore2x#configuring-session)

Comment: @Fabio btw you should edit the question and remove *all* references to ASP.NET Identity. Anyone who reads the question without the comments will assume you are confusing authentication and session

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos my app is just a simple micro crm, the problem is only for the development phase

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Question edited, i hope is more understandable now

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET Sessions were never related to authentication. They use their own storage to store temporary data that is used during a singel user session.

In ASP.NET Core the Session middleware *always* [uses the service registered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?tabs=aspnetcore2x#working-with-session-state) for IDistributedCache. The default implementation is a local in-memory cache :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache.
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    });
}
```

There are two persistent storage providers, [one for Redis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed#using-a-redis-distributed-cache) and one for [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed#using-a-sql-server-distributed-cache). To use them simply replace the call to `AddDistributedMemoryCache()`, eg :

```
services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options =>
{
    options.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=DistCache;Integrated Security=True;";
    options.SchemaName = "dbo";
    options.TableName = "TestCache";
});
```

The linked doc page explains how to configure the providers.

All three providers can be found in the [ASP.NET\Caching](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching) repository. You can use them as a starting point to implement your own provider, eg to use MySQL, assuming there isn't one already available.

You can also configure ASP.NET Core to use the in-memory cache for general caching and SQL Server or Redis for distributed caching and session storage, eg :

```
services.AddMemoryCache();
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
{
    options.Configuration = "localhost";
    options.InstanceName = "SampleInstance";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The default session store is in-memory, mostly because every other type of store requires some type of configuration. When you have anything that's stored in-memory (session, cache, etc.) it's inherently process-bound, so when the process terminates, everything stored in-memory goes along with it. Rebuilding a running web app causes the process to be terminated and restarted, so there's your issue in a nutshell.

If you want the session to persist, then you need to use *a persistent store*, i.e. SQL Server, Redis, etc. The [ASP.NET Core Distributed Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed) (which is what ASP.NET Core uses for sessions) documentation covers how to to set all that up.